# How to detect specific css when the dom changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension and I am disabling the mouse for the entire page + by getting all the dom elements and then filtering out the ones that had the cursor pointer using getComputed styles. It works fine, but on single page sites, for example, twitter, the elements keep on adding based on the user interaction, i.e. there is no page load event I can look after. for example if someone add a comment, than it would create new element and I am not sure how to get the cursor pointer for that one too.

If I click on a button which injects a button on the page, how to get the cursor property of that element added on the dom. What can be a good way to approach and solve this problem elegantly

It would be great help if you can show a small example :)

Thank you

Comment: @Yogi, I tried MutationObserver, but not sure whether its a good practise, and it would give the parent element that had changed, and when I try filtering out, it won't work because it just query from the parent elements changed, not their childs too

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried using MutationObserver because it does seem like the obvious way forward.

Comment: There's probably no need to process any elements if you add a high priority CSS override like `*:not(#\0) { point-events:none !important }`

Comment: @wOxxOm, This seems to be solving my problem, absolutely it disables the entire mouse from the page, but how can I remove it after user permits? i.e. to make it the way it was like before?

Comment: It depends on how you add the CSS. You can do it inside your js content script by adding a `style` DOM element and then removing it or in your popup (background) script via chrome.scripting.insertCSS and removeCSS.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Hello, I tried setting the cursor for the entire page, but it seems that it won't work on some places, like when I inject the css on stackoverflow, it won't work on stackoverflow snippet run code and I have seen it won't be working on some other places too

Comment: Use devtools to inspect the problem. You'll probably see it's an iframe.

Comment: @wOxxOm, is there any way to disable the cursor from the iframe too?

Comment: Use [all_frames](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#frames).

Comment: @wOxxOm, I am injecting the scripts manually into the page using chrome.scripting.executeScript, how can I specify allframes true with this?

Comment: Check its documentation, it has a similar parameter.